# Is the word 'crony' common for native speakers?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

[image: Oxford Dictionary entry for crony]According to this [source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crony) the word 'crony' is Cambridge **university slang**;  Maybe is **too geeky** to call someone this way instead of a guy, fellow?

synonym: guy, fellow, bro etc.

#### My question:

#### Can I use this word instead of the words as 'GUY', 'FELLOW', 'PAL' etc?

Comment: That's not what the source says.

Comment: Special for you @userr2684291 I inserted the picture. Please read the origin section. Thank you for your attention

Comment: @Max - *(**originally** Cambridge university slang)* merely gives some background. Nowhere does this source say that it is currently slang - so one would correctly infer that it is ***not*** slang today.

Comment: @Davo Nowhere did I say that it is **current** slang too. It's not the point of my question

Comment: There does not appear to be a clear question here. You should make clear the context in which you want to use "crony", and explain why the usage advice "Derogatory/informal" doesn't answer your question.  The source indicates that it **was** university slang in the **17th century**. It is **now** used informally.

Comment: @ James K . What really isn't clear in this question _(Maybe is too geeky to call someone this way, instead of a guy, fellow?)_

Comment: Can I use this word instead of the words as 'GUY', 'FELLOW', 'PAL' - **Is it common word OR it would sound weird or geeky**

Comment: Max, don’t put your question in the title of the question. People may not see it there. (Plus, it makes your title too long.) Also, @JamesK is right – when trying to figure out whether or not a word is okay to use, look at the usage cues in blue italics, not the etymological information in the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crony has changed its meaning over time: now its meaning is pretty sinister on both sides of the herring pond. I would advise against using it about a personal friend of yours.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crony) has this to say about it:

> a friend, or a person who works for someone in authority, especially one who is willing to give and receive dishonest help

Meanwhile, if you look at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crony), the definition seems quite innocuous:

> a close friend especially of long standing

but look at the examples:

> The mayor rewarded his cronies with high-paying jobs after he was elected.
>
> the criminal's cronies were also closely questioned about the illegal gambling operation

Comment: I've just asked the same question on another source; The same answer I've [got](https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/61gnde/is_the_word_crony_common_for_native_speakers_can/) (from California)

Comment: The only way I have read this recently is as [*Crony capitalism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crony_capitalism). The meaning would be similar to your first example.